# Which is the best approach when the new version of my application is changing how it reads and write a file?

Tags: android, file, architecture, language-agnostic

Users of my android application can decide to save their projects, so a file will be created storing all the needed variable and fields.

Now, I have prepared an update which includes more fields and variables to save.

All ok so far, but suddenly I thought that when the user will try to load old projects with the last release there will be failures.

Which is the best approach to avoid that?

Comment: In the updated version of your application, you need a way to distinguish between OLD and NEW versions of the project files in your loading code. Assuming that you have a custom file structure you will need to a clever way of figuring out which version each file is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact data you are working with but I would go with saving the data to a database with versioning. This way if you change your database you can prepare an UPGRADE tasks to migrate old databases to the new ones. Ofcourse the same thing you can do with the file but it will be less intuitive than db.

Comment: but it's late already as I have it in production saving on files.

Comment: It is not too late. Consider releasing new version of your app that migrates from file to db for the old users (if you want to save their info) and from that point on work with db which will make it easier for you to maintain the structure. It is much better than inventing logic to maintain your proprietary file data changes. If you still want to work with file for some reason (depends on the data size) move to storing json, which will be much easier to change later on.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, versioning...
Android database uses it, and that's the (probably) best way to handle this problem.

In your file you could create a variable for the current file version, and based on this version a method or other method will be called in your code, there are many ways you can come up with a numbering system...

The problem with this is that you will have to maintain the code for all versions, but then again, that's the way it is.

If your server data (in case you communicate with a server) sends a different format, you will also need to make some sort of versioning.

In my android projects i have a Definitions class in a utils package...

```
public class Definitions {
    private static Integer VERSION;
    private static final String BASEURL;

    public static Integer getVersion() {
        //read the version variable in the file
        // and return the correct version
    }

    public static String getBASEURL() {
        if (Definitions.getVersion() == null){ //file does not have any version variable
            return "http://myserver.com/v1/";
        }
        else if (Definitions.getVersion() == 2){
            return "http://myserver.com/v2/";
        }
        return "http://myserver.com/v3/";
    }
}
```

then in other classes you can do Definitions.getVersion() and treat accordingly, if you have new variables that is not in the current version of the file you can as